# How to build an attachment to support lens?

Tags: nikon, dslr, sensor, nikon-d5200

I am using a D5200 and want to make an attachment to **support the lens *at a distance away* from the camera body.** (There will be *no* lens mounted to the camera. Then there will be a gap. Then the lens.)

Because the lens support will be off-camera, and all components have to be aligned along the optical axis, the vertical height of the center of the center from the base of the camera is important. I am not able to find any reference/documentation online pertaining to this.

Any help, suggestions, or references for building this support, or finding the vertical height of the center of the sensor from the base of the body, would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite get this. _Why_ is the height from the base of the body relevant? It's centered in the _lens_.

Comment: @mattdm Because I am building a lens support which will be off-camera and all components has to be aligned along the optical axis. This requires the height of the sensor from the base of the camera.

Comment: I still don't get that — if you're supporting the lens, the camera will come along for free.

Comment: @mattdm perhaps I'll finish my setup and share a picture to explain.i am supporting the lens not attached to the camera but aligned to the camera sensor

Comment: You mean, there will be no lens mounted to the camera at all, and you will have a gap and then some non-standard lens?

Comment: @mattdm yes. Precisely!

Comment: Like a [bellows](https://amzn.to/2ui0yXX)?

Comment: @mattdm I am making use of two lens - reversed wide angle lens close to the body and a zoom lens in regular orientation in from of it. This will help in achieving greater  magnification from a distance. Tried it with handheld conditions but need to design mechanical support to get the task going. And to design the mechanical support, need height of the optical axis!

Comment: @xiota yes. I can buy one or need the asked information to build one!

Comment: What are you photographing that needs such an odd lens arrangement?

Comment: @xiota I am working in a university lab to image droplets from a distance. Long distance microscopes are costly and not available immediately in the working range we are looking for. So exploring options to get some high magnification from dslr lenses!

Comment: How long distance is this? centimeters, meters, ... ???  If pre-existing bellows are long enough, you can use reverse mounting rings to connect a lens to the camera and bellows. Then mount the other lens at the other end. The bellows will keep the lenses in alignment, and the reverse mounting rings will keep it all aligned with the camera body.

Comment: How is this different from a telescope?

Comment: @xiota oh. I will check this bellow! My requirement is 1m and above. Magnification is the limitation when using the usual zoom lens(300mm)

Comment: @xiota operational distance of a telescope is huge. Also it is meant for resolving but not magnification!

Comment: bellows are usually shorter than a metter, but you can use the same idea, just keep everything in alignment via the lens mounts.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add info you just gave in comments about what you are trying to photograph, long-distance microscopes vs telescopes, etc.? Maybe also link to resource so people can read about what a long-distance microscope is and what it's used for. And add "macro" and "microscopy" tags?

Comment: @xiota okay! Will do

Answer (score 18):

> I am using a D5200 and wish to find the height of the centre of the sensor from the base of the body.

I don't know the number, but you should be able to measure the distance easily enough. It's a good bet that the sensor is centered within the lens mounting flange, so you really only need to measure from the inside edge of the flange to the bottom of the body, and also measure the inside diameter of the flange. You can take both measurements very accurately with a [vernier caliper](https://smile.amazon.com/NORTOOLS-Professional-Vernier-Stainless-0-02mm-Strictly/dp/B072MF3GHS). Add the radius of the flange (half the diameter) to the flange to base measurement, and you should have the distance to the center of the sensor.

Answer (score 8):

Usually the distance from the center of the sensor to the base of the camera isn't considered when designing a rail support because accessories such as batteries or matt boxes and lenses all **add** an additional unknown distance to that measurement; instead the support attached to the rail is adjustable.

Example [GenusTech Rail Support](https://www.genustech.tv/collections/camera-baseplates/products/universal-adaptor-bar-system-special):

- DSLR

[image: DSLR Rail]

[image: Adjustable Base]

- Video Camera

[image: Complete Unit]

[image: Adjustable Base]

By building (or buying for less than U$200) an adjustable base and rail holder you can accommodate different cameras and accessories. By using the distance from the center of a D5200 sensor to its base to design a rail holder you will be limited in the number of cameras that will fit.

If the lens is long enough to require support there's bound to be some differences in the diameters of different long lenses that aren't going to be accommodated by a non-adjustable setup.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I will look into making an adjustable stand. Sounds very versatile. Also, the reference images are giving me good ideas for modifying my original design! Thanks

Comment: @karthikeyan - Glad to be of help. If you were to edit your answer to explain how that distance would assist your design **and** if you own that camera presently upon which to make physical measurements (as another answer has suggested) perhaps we could improve our answers; assisting you to choose one as your preferred answer.

Comment: I think I went with the vernier caliper. Yes I own the camera. And I did end up taking measurements!

Comment: @karthikeyan I got the impression that you were intending to remove the lens from the camera and were designing and optical system to hold off-camera lens elements at the correct location along the optical axis of the image system.  Is this the case?  If yes, then this doesn't really answer your question, I don't think.

Comment: @karthikeyan - Thanks for your reply. It seemed from the question that you were designing the device for someone else or prior to purchase, that's why you didn't know the measurement.

Comment: @J... Yes, you got it right in guessing that I am making arrangements for off-camera elements to be aligned with the optical axis of the sensor. But I dont get why this method of measuring the height wont work?

Answer (score 1):

The center of the sensor is at the same height and width of the center of the lens mount. If you search for the plane where the sensor is: There is a symbol on the body (a little circle with a long line thru it). That shows the position.

Comment: oh and also the nikon f-mount has a fixed distance between f-mount and sensor. you can google for it.

Comment: The sensor plane mark on the body indicates the forward/back location of the sensor plane. It doesn't indicate at all where the sensor is located vertically (with respect to the tripod mount, for instance). But your point about being aligned with the center of the lens mount is spot on.

Comment: if it was not clear: i also mean just the forward/back location of the sensor plane

Comment: It wasn't exactly clear to me, but after re-reading, I see your meaning. Being a _plane_, it can only be located front/back. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would normally suggest finding the information in the [Entrance Pupil Database](https://wiki.panotools.org/Entrance_Pupil_Database) at Panotools.org. However, unfortunately there is no entry in the table for the Nikon D5200. =(

*(Leaving this answer for future reference for similar questions)*

Answer (score 1):

**Use an Optical Rail as the basis of your system.**

The [Ealing company](http://www.ealingcatalog.com/opto-mechanics.html) supplies electro-optical laboratory supplies that would be suitable and affordable for this project.

All the equipment is optical laboratory (accurate) grade. Everything is adjustable. The student/economy line I suggest is currently on clearance for about half its normal price.

The TriRail optomechanical equipment short list is:

- [TriRail **optical rail** for holding, aligning, and using the components](http://www.ealingcatalog.com/opto-mechanics/optical-rails/trirail-triangular-optical-rails.html).
- [TriRail carrier for the camera body and one for the lens](http://www.ealingcatalog.com/opto-mechanics/optical-rails/trirail-carriers.html)
- [Mounting post](http://www.ealingcatalog.com/opto-mechanics/mounting-hardware.html) and [Lens Clamp](http://www.ealingcatalog.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=lens%20clamp) to hold the lens on the optical rail carrier